# Converter segundos em dias

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma dúvida muito simples: Como converter segundos em dias? tentei usando:

```
<?php echo date('d', $userstats['OnlineTime']); ?>
```

mas vai somente até 31 dias.

```
<?php
   $userstats_a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_stats INNER JOIN users ON user_stats.id = users.id WHERE users.Rank <5 ORDER BY user_stats.OnlineTime DESC LIMIT 5");

   while($userstats = mysql_fetch_assoc($userstats_a)){
   ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um dia tem 86400 segundos ( 60 * 60 * 24 ).

Para converter segundos em dias:

```
$dias = $segundos / 86400;
```

Se não quiser decimais, arredondando para baixo:

```
$dias = floor( $segundos / 86400 );
```

arredondando para cima:

```
$dias = ceil( $segundos / 86400 );
```

Manual das principais funções de arredondamento:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.floor.php
>
> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ceil.php
>
> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.round.php

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer uma operação no próprio `SELECT`:

```
SELECT OnlineTime / 60 / 24 AS Tempo FROM user_stats INNER JOIN users ON user_stats.id = users.id WHERE users.Rank <5 ORDER BY user_stats.OnlineTime DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Você está transformando dias em minutos, não segundos em dias

Comment: Olá, não funcionou....

Answer (score -1):

Você pode obter o resultado esperado utilizando a classe *DateTime*, veja o exemplo:

Criamos uma função para facilitar o uso:

```
function converterSegundos($segundos, $formato) {
    $dtF = new \DateTime('@0');
    $dtT = new \DateTime("@$segundos");
    return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format($formato);
}
```

Agora para utilizar basta chamar a função informando um formato, abaixo retorna em segundos.

```
// 6 segundos
echo converterSegundos(6, '%s segundos');
```

Agora somente minutos:

```
// 6 minutos
echo converterSegundos(369, '%i minutos');
```

Podes retornar a hora:

```
// 10 horas
echo converterSegundos(36000, '%h horas');
```

Podes retornar os dias:

```
// 60 dias
echo converterSegundos(5184000, '%a dias');
```

Ou

```
// 60 dias, 0 horas, 0 minutos e 0 segundos
echo converterSegundos(5184000, '%a dias, %h horas, %i minutos e %s segundos');
```

> Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/OIYv/0)

#### Referência

- [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php)

Comment: Também não funcionou...